# unable to add Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to access RIA services from a non-silverlight client.  On my dev machine I have no problem adding the domainServices endPoints

```
<domainServices>
      <endpoints>
        <add name="soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <!--<add name="JSON" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />-->
      </endpoints>
</domainServices>
```

Howerver that same config on the staging server  and the DomainService throws an exception:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.get_ComplexTypes()'.

I've verified that all the project references hae Copy Local set to true and that the

> Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

dll is in fact on the web server.

**Update:** I should add that the error seems to occur during compilation:
ServiceActivationException: The service '...' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Method not found:

What am I missing?

Comment: mmm dummy question: is a different version of the WCF Ria Service Toolkit already installed on the production server ?

Comment: @mCasameto, Not a dumb question, and as far as I can tell the answer is no, there is nothing in the GAC, and the DLL is copied locally in the deployment.  I would love to know where it's getting it's code from, such that it can't compile

Comment: Uninstalling the RIA Services toolkit on server did the trick, although I thought I was certain that the GAC didn't have the assembly.